# SpritekitNode added programmatically does not trigger the touchesBegan while the same spritekitnode added through scene editor works

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I added a SKSpriteNode(name=building1) to a scene programmatically and it does not fire the touchesBegan function. So I tried to add a spritenode (name=building2, parent = GameScene) through the scene editor (using the same texture) and that works fine. I can see both the buildings but only the 2nd one fires the touchesBegan function.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {    
var build = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    build = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "build")
    build.name = "building1"
    build.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    build.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    build.zPosition = 0
    build.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addChild(build)

}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    print("Something was touched")
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if atPoint(location).name! == "building1" {
            print("\(atPoint(location).name!) was touched")
        }
        if atPoint(location).name! == "building2" {
            print("\(atPoint(location).name!) was touched")
        }
    }

}


}
```

The weird thing is that when I touch building2(added through the scene editor), I get the output "Something was touched" "building2 was touched" while building1 does not even fire the function i.e nothing is displayed in the logs. 
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line and it should work:

```
build.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

It may seem weird at first. The whole point is to make the user interact with the node, why should I disable user interaction?

Well, this is what the docs say for `isUserInteractionEnabled`:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the node receives touch events.

So if we set it to true, the node, not the scene will receive touch events. Therefore, the scene's `touchesBegan` method is not called. Instead, the node's `touchesBegan` is called. If we set it to false however, the node will not receive any touch events. So where do the touch events go? To the parent of the node (the scene, in this case)!

The node that you added from the editor has `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` by default.

Comment: Yes, that worked!! And here I thought I was being all through with my code. Thanks

Comment: I added the 2nd sprite to see if I had missed something. Unfortunately, I dont think the isUserInteractionEnabled property shows up in the Attributes Inspector. In any case that is indeed a subtle point and thank you for taking the time to explain.